# How to MongoDBimport json tree not as one document?

Tags: php, json, mongodb, tree

I've got a this json file to import:

```
   {"Spele": {
     "Laiks": "2017/01/11",
     "Skatitaji": 6740,
     "Vieta": "Newlands Stadium",
     "T": [
      {
       "Uzvards": "Antamo",
       "Vards": "Dennis"
      },
      {
       "Uzvards": "Prompa",
       "Vards": "Pedro"
      }
     ],
     "Komanda": [
      {
       "Nosaukums": "Barcelona",
       "Speletaji": {"Speletajs": [
        {
         "Loma": "V",
         "Nr": 16,
         "Uzvards": "Sam",
         "Vards": "Sidney"
        },
        {
         "Loma": "A",
         "Nr": 17,
         "Uzvards": "Cisovsky",
         "Vards": "Marian"
        }
}
]
}
```

But unfortunately, mongoDBimport imports it as one document. Are there any tips on how to manage trees? I can work with mongo.exe or PHP.
maybe manually adding:

```
"_id" : { "$oid" : "50906d7fa3c412bb040eb577" }
```

Would solve it?

Comment: what exactly you mean when you say tree ? how would you want your saved document to look like ?

Comment: I want to be able to query it atleast. But when I query my document, it returns the whole document like in this other post I made. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48128835/how-to-query-a-deeply-nested-json-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have been working with a similar project some times ago and i parse those as php variables and than store them in database using sql query

first decode json using the follow code:

$response is your json file

```
$data = json_decode($response);
```

than you can use this to take data and store to a variable

```
$newvat = $data->myjson->prices;
```